# Filtering on one dimension retaining shape of array

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to selectively filter a numpy array, but still retain the shape of the returned mask.

The filtering should apply to dimension `[:, 1]`, but still return `False` for all other dimension elements (for the set of `[:,:] - [:, 1]`).

This is what my result is when I filter on `[:, 1]`:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> a[:,1] > 3
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

but I really like a mixture of both (have the shape of the following mask)

```
>>> a[:,:] > 3
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

So I think in this case the expected result would be

```
                 +-- this is the dimension the filter condition should be applied to
                 V
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

**Update**

I may have found a way to do this:

```
>>> a[:,[False,True,False]] > 3
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Looks what I am trying to do (filter on all from dimension 0 `:`, filter on index 1 in dimension 1 `[False, True, False]`). How would I do this efficiently (helper functions?) when not knowing the exact length of a dimension (or even without even generating a lengthy bool array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to preset the mask false and fill only the column of interest

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])

mask = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=np.bool)

mask[:,1] = a[:,1] > 3

print mask
```

Returning

```
[[False False False]
 [False  True False]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this would work. One thing I am worried about is the overhead of this operation. The array I am looking at is quite large (a few 10k elements).